# Can I disable dictionary in postgres ts_vector / ts_query full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.1

I need to do a text search on machine language. If I use any of the available text search dictonaries, the ts_vectors are messing up.

> ex. move -> becomes mov and my searching is failing.

any Idea how to index non- lingual words?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the `simple` dictionary with an empty stop word file?

Create an empty stop word file `$(pg_config --sharedir)/tsearch_data/empty.stop` and run:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY machine (
   TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
   STOPWORDS = empty
);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION machine (
   PARSER = default
);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION machine
   ADD MAPPING FOR asciiword, word, numword, asciihword, hword,
                   numhword, hword_asciipart, hword_part,
                   hword_numpart, email, protocol, url, host,
                   url_path, file, sfloat, float, int, uint,
                   version, tag, entity, blank
   WITH machine;
```

Then you can get:

```
test=> SELECT * FROM ts_debug('machine', 'move');
   alias   |   description   | token | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes
-----------+-----------------+-------+--------------+------------+---------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | move  | {machine}    | machine    | {move}
(1 row)
```

If you want this configuration by default (so you don't have to specify `'machine'` all the time), change the parameter `default_text_search_config` appropriately.

Comment: thanks! just a doubt though, will this work with XML field?